# Can i build an application with basics of a programing & codes researching?

Tags: android, ios

Can I build an application with  basics of a programming & codes researching ?

my question is that can I build an app with the basics of a programming language like Python and researching on internet on codes that I will need to use on my application.

Thank's.

Comment: I'm sure it is possible to program an app in Python but you will probably have to look into 3rd party frameworks. I would recommend Java for android and Swift for iOS if you are staying platform specific.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do. You've to just brush up life cycle of app in iOS & Android e.g. view and activity. All languages are same in semantics except syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible. Using basics try with small applications.

After that you can implement advance concepts on these applications with some research and practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another programming language like python and many more to build up android and IOS application but you can't  build up and default functionality as you can  built up and developed by using native programming languages.
I would like suggest that if your are targeting android then you should go for android and if you are targeting IOS then you should go for swift instead of choosing another language.
The reason behind this is that if you spend lots of time to implement something  by using another programming language like python ,there is no guarantee whether you will success or not.
if you are choosing native programming language  to implement anything it would be easy to implement anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is very possible.

Anyone who  understands code can write code Programming languages doesn't matter. Most of us does the same, we know little about our environment and try to come up with a solution but if we are stuck we all search over internet to find the solution. If we can do it so can you.

Just start off by writing some code for your first App and gradually you'll improve with a good pace.
Hope this help, keep coding keep learning!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible however researching for codes alone might not be enough to gain a deep understanding about creating apps. It is better if you choose first which mobile platform do you want to pursue (iOS or Android) then start researching about the basics like using its IDE and the app lifecycle. Then create simple mobile apps until you get used to it.

P.S. This is also based from my experience because I also had a hard time learning how to create apps before.